# STAGE creates bag files with a wrong timestamp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
in these days, i've tried to create bag files by recording messages generated by STAGE robot simulator.
The problem is that every bag file generated has a timestamp associated to the date of linux's birth (january 1st, 1970).
I tried twice and I got same problem. This doesn't happen if i generate a custom topic, write on it by my code and store messages in a bag file. in this case, bag file has a correct timestamp.

could you tell me how to force system to write properly timestamps for bags generated by STAGE?
thanks for support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51039/stage-creates-bag-files-with-a-wrong-timestamp/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stage generates simulated time, which begins at zero (Jan. 1, 1970).

I don't know how to change that.

If you run another node in the same ROS graph with [/use_sim_time](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic) set, it should generate compatible timestamps with the messages stage publishes.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-25**:
As Jack mentions the intended behavior is to have all nodes running with /use_sim_time.  This allows everything to remain syncronized even if the sim runs faster or slower than real time.

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-26**:
thanks for your answer. i started roscore, then i wrote
rosparam set /use_sim_time true.
Then i wrote
rosbag play --clock bag1.bag bag2.bag
nothing happened. execution of first bag continues to last 40 years since his 1970 timestamp. maybe i mistooke somewhere. do u know where?

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-26**:
moreover: how to tell STAGE node to run with /use_sim_time?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-14**:
Set the /use_sim_time parameter before running Stage. Running rosbag with the --clock option causes it to publish the /clock topic, not what you want when running Stage.